# The size of Git repository become 2x old size after prune

Tags: git, gitlab

I use GitLab Community Edition 8.15.1 1119c1f, Git 2.11 (at my PC), Windows 10 pro x64.

My Git repository has more than 15500 commit. After run command

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf module_foo/deployment/lib' HEAD
```

about 6 hours,

I try

```
git push origin --force --all -v
```

I try to cut down the size of Git repository (by delete *.jar files in library), but it become **2x old size**. Then I see (on GitLab web GUI) the size of Git repsitory from 400 MB to 800 MB, What's wrong?

Comment: `git gc --prune=now`

Comment: At client, before the command `git push origin --force --all -v`?

Comment: Before or after, doesn't matter. If do after, just push again. But you have to keep in mind that size of *yours* repository might be quite different to *peer's* (one you communicating with).

Answer (score 3):

This is to be expected, because `git filter-branch` works—as it must—by *copying* every filtered commit.  If you run it over every commit, the end result is about twice as many commits.  But don't panic!  You just need to *re-clone*.  For details, read through all the background below.

## References

Remember that the way Git works is based on *references*.  The most common references are branch and tag names.  For instance, you probably have a `master` branch (and perhaps that's your *only* branch).  This means that the name `master` translates into a Git SHA-1 hash ID.  Try running the command:

```
git rev-parse master
```

in your shell, to see the actual hash ID.

#### Name spaces of references

The branch name `master` is actually the *reference* `refs/heads/master`.  A reference is just a generalized branch or tag name.  If you have a tag named `v1.2`, for instance, that's really just the reference name `refs/tags/v1.2`.  Note that these are all under `refs/`, but the *branches* are under `refs/heads/` while the tags are under `refs/tags/`.

These top level names create [*name spaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), which allow multiple different names to co-exist without any possibility of collision.  That way if you accidentally create a *tag* `master`, it won't collide with the *branch* `master` (it's still a bad idea—Git will handle it, but you're likely to confuse yourself).

Git's *remote-tracking branches* similarly live in a `refs/` name-space, namely `refs/remotes/`, followed by the name of the remote.  Hence `origin/master` is really `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

#### References only point to one commit; each commit points to another

All these reference names—branches, tags, remote-tracking branches, and special things like `refs/stash` for `git stash`—each point to *one specific commit*.<sup>1</sup>  The way Git finds all the *rest* of the commits in your repository is to start from each of these single commits.  Each commit has, inside it, some IDs of some other, earlier commits.  Most commits have one previous commit.  At least one commit—the first one you ever made—has *no* previous commit, and any merge commit has two previous commits,<sup>2</sup> as it ties together those commits.

**Most of the time, you don't need to know all of this**.  But, **when you run `git filter-branch`**, it saves all the *original* references into `refs/original/`.  These original references point to the original commits, the ones that you had before `git filter-branch` copied them all.  Then **it replaces the values in each of the references** to point to the *copied* commits.

**This is where your doubled repository size comes from.**  Note that if you did mess things up a bit with the original `filter-branch`, you can get everything back by "undoing" the filter-branch, by moving all the `refs/originals/` references back to their original names (i.e., removing the *new* references and putting the originals back instead).  You'll still retain the larger repository size, but the new copies will no longer be used, and will eventually expire (and won't be carried across new clones).

Note also that you usually want to filter *all* branches, with `-- --all`.  If you have any *annotated tags*, you usually want to include a `--tag-name-filter cat` to cause the tags to be adjusted as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or, for annotated tags, the reference will point to an annotated tag object, which will then point to the commit.  Non-branch reference names can point to any of Git's internal object types, though anything other than "commit" or "tag" is unusual.

<sup>2</sup>A merge commit can point back to more than two previous commits.  This is called an *octopus merge*.  An octopus merge is mainly useful for showing off your Git-fu. :-)  That is, it does nothing you could not have done with several regular merges.

---

#### Shrinking the repository

The reason `git filter-branch` saves all those originals is that filter-branch can be extremely destructive.  This gives you that escape hatch to get your originals back if you need them.

Usually, the right way to use filter-branch is to run it on a *copy* of the repository.  Then it would not matter if things get mangled, and there would be no need to save everything.  (Because of Git's internal mechanisms and constraints, you would *still* get copies, but filter-branch could then clean them out for you.)  But "just in case" it leaves all the originals around.

The easy way to shrink it, then, is to clone the repository *again* right *after* filtering.  The clone *omits* the `refs/originals/` references, and therefore skips copying all the saved original objects as well.  So you will immediately see the new clone drop way back in size.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you help me few pragmatic commands? (1) After run `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf module_foo/deployment/lib' HEAD`, how to push to remote without lost branches? (2) How to push to remote (don't need recreate remote old repository, and the size of Git repository don't become 2x old size)?

Comment: `filter-branch` only modifies (and copies) the branches (and tags) you specify. Once copied, you must force-push to any place you would normally push without force, because the copied commits are no longer historically-related to the original commits. So `git push -f <branch>`, or if you filtered all branches, `git push -f 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'`. If you used a tag-name filter, you must force-push the tags as well, though this will be less successful if anyone else has an existing clone.

Comment: Note that `git push` does not push `refs/originals/` at all by default, so this won't push the extra commits. You have no control over the size of the remote repository though: that's up to *their* Git to compact.

Answer (score 0):

I do these step, create full backup:

```
git clone --mirror http://example.com/git/foo.git
cd foo.git
git bundle create foo.bundle --all
```

Then delete repository named `foo`,
then

```
git push origin --force --all -v
```

The size will be like expected (don't become to 2x old size).